# Xcode 4.3: how to create a nib linked to a view controller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

Sorry, I'm quite new with xcode with a quite big project.
I upgrade xcode to 4.3.
I have a project (that doesn't use storyboard) and I need to add a view controller with a nib file.

Before upgrading I did File --> Ne File --> Cocoa Objective-C subclass and xcode created for me the m/h and their nib file.
Now that that option is disappear, how can I add a view controller?

I created the Objective-C class and, separately, a nib file, but how can I link the H/m files to the nib??

How can the m file call is nib??

Please can you help me? The project is real big and I can rewrite the code with the storyboard option!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing your XIB, go to the Identity Inspector (it's the third button show in the following image). Then where it says Class, choose the controller you want to associate with the XIB.

[image]

Comment: It returned me an error until I linked the view in IBOutlet.     

    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',reason:    '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "xxx" nib but the    view outlet    was not set.'

I connected the File's Owner to the View in IB.

Now it works.

Comment: Set the view for that controller. Drag `File's Owner` to the view you want to show and select it as the view.